# Not able to send packets in scapy on python3/Mac OS

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I am new to scapy and was trying to send an icmp packet using my wireless interface. I keep getting following error. I am using the latest scapy version on python3.  When i try to send packet using python3 shell i keep getting segmentation fault 11 error. Both sr and send is failing.

```
bash-3.2$ ifconfig en1
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 24:a0:74:ef:c2:0a 
inet6 fe80::1421:2877:9b9f:8b7e%en1 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x5 
inet 192.168.0.56 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
media: autoselect
status: active
bash-3.2$ ping -S 192.168.0.56 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.166.68) from 192.168.0.56: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.166.68: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=26.458 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.166.68: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=21.927 ms



bASH-3.2$ scapy
WARNING: Cannot read wireshark manuf database 
WARNING: Crypto-related methods disabled for IPsec, Dot11 and TLS 
         layers (needs python-cryptography v1.7+).
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
INFO: Can't import python-cryptography v1.7+. Disabled WEP 
decryption/encryption.
INFO: Can't import python-cryptography v1.7+. Disabled IPsec 
encryption/authentication.
WARNING: IPython not available. Using standard Python shell instead.
AutoCompletion, History are disabled.

                   aSPY//YASa       
           apyyyyCY//////////YCa       |
          sY//////YSpcs  scpCY//Pp     | Welcome to Scapy
 ayp ayyyyyyySCP//Pp           syY//C    | Version 2.4.0rc4
 AYAsAYYYYYYYY///Ps              cY//S   |
     pCCCCY//p          cSSps y//Y   | https://github.com/secdev/scapy
     SPPPP///a          pP///AC//Y   |
          A//A            cyP////C   | Have fun!
          p///Ac            sC///a   |
          P////YCpc           A//A   | To craft a packet, you have to be a
   scccccp///pSP///p          p//Y   | packet, and learn how to swim in
  sY/////////y  caa           S//P   | the wires and in the waves.
   cayCyayP//Ya              pY/Ya   |        -- Jean-Claude Van Damme
    sY/PsY////YCc          aC//Yp    |
     sc  sccaCY//PCypaapyCP//YSs  
              spCPY//////YPSps    
                   ccaacs         

>>> sr(IP(dst='www.google.com')/ICMP())
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy-2.4.0rc4-
py2.7.egg/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 364, in sr
s = conf.L3socket(promisc=promisc, filter=filter, iface=iface, 
nofilter=nofilter)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy-2.4.0rc4-
py2.7.egg/scapy/arch/bpf/supersocket.py", line 57, in __init__
(self.ins, self.dev_bpf) = get_dev_bpf()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scapy-2.4.0rc4-
py2.7.egg/scapy/arch/bpf/core.py", line 98, in get_dev_bpf
raise Scapy_Exception("No /dev/bpf handle is available !")
Scapy_Exception: No /dev/bpf handle is available
```

Comment: Is this a known issue? tried updating the scapy to the latest version from the github repository.  Is this the latest version which is compatible with python3 on macos 'Version 2.4.0rc4.dev94'.

Comment: I tried the same using ./run_scapy and both send and sr1 works properly. Not sure why the transmission of packets fails when we source scapy through python shell.

Comment: I suggest that you open a bug before 2.4.0 is released! https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/new

Comment: Thanks. Opened a new bug.

Answer (score 3):

Try it with `sudo scapy`, it worked for me.

Here where I found the solution:
https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1343

guedou commented on 8 Sep  **Scapy needs to be run as root to send
packets.**

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue, but also for just sniffing packets (i.e., not to send, which I know needs root). So just starting `scapy` and running `>>> sniff()` would return `Scapy_Exception: No /dev/bpf handle is available`.

It turns out that by default the /dev/bpf* devices are owned by `wheel`, which my regular user is not part of. This is why `sudo scapy` works. The issue is that running under sudo is not always convenient.

I don't know if the /dev/bpf* devices be owned by any other group, but a quick workaround indicates that they can ...

Just install Wireshark! Once wireshark is installed, the /dev/bpf* devices are owned by `access_bpf`, a group that the non-root user is added into.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue running with scapy as user with admin rights on Mac.

The solution is to run as super user - sudo

I tried it on both python 2.7.17 and 3.7.6. 
Make sure you have the updated scapy package, see installation instruction on https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

The root admin rights for scapy are listed in the following github issue doc https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1851