# scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: Can't attach the BPF filter

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, bpf

I found a WiFi scanner written in python on youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFTwB2nAexs
Direct GitHub script link: https://github.com/davidbombal/red-python-scripts/blob/main/lanscan_arp.py

But I'm having an issue with BPF filter as "***scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: Can't attach the BPF filter !***"

script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Import scapy
import scapy.all as scapy

# We need to create regular expressions to ensure that the input is correctly formatted.
import re

# Basic user interface header
print(
    r"""______            _     _  ______                 _           _ 
|  _  \          (_)   | | | ___ \               | |         | |
| | | |__ ___   ___  __| | | |_/ / ___  _ __ ___ | |__   __ _| |
| | | / _` \ \ / / |/ _` | | ___ \/ _ \| '_ ` _ \| '_ \ / _` | |
| |/ / (_| |\ V /| | (_| | | |_/ / (_) | | | | | | |_) | (_| | |
|___/ \__,_| \_/ |_|\__,_| \____/ \___/|_| |_| |_|_.__/ \__,_|_|"""
)
print("\n****************************************************************")
print("\n* Copyright of David Bombal, 2021                              *")
print("\n* https://www.davidbombal.com                                  *")
print("\n* https://www.youtube.com/davidbombal                          *")
print("\n****************************************************************")

# Regular Expression Pattern to recognise IPv4 addresses.
ip_add_range_pattern = re.compile("^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]*$")

# Get the address range to ARP
while True:
    ip_add_range_entered = input(
        "\nPlease enter the ip address and range that you want to send the ARP request to (ex 192.168.1.0/24): "
    )
    if ip_add_range_pattern.search(ip_add_range_entered):
        print(f"{ip_add_range_entered} is a valid ip address range")
        break


# Try ARPing the ip address range supplied by the user.
# The arping() method in scapy creates a pakcet with an ARP message
# and sends it to the broadcast mac address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff.
# If a valid ip address range was supplied the program will return
# the list of all results.
arp_result = scapy.arping(ip_add_range_entered)
```

output

```
Please enter the ip address and range that you want to send the ARP request to (ex 192.168.1.0/24): 192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.0/24 is a valid ip address range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/belgra/Development/WiFi Scanner/lan_scan_arp.py", line 41, in <module>
    arp_result = scapy.arping(ip_add_range_entered)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 734, in arping
    ans, unans = srp(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 675, in srp
    s = iface.l2socket()(promisc=promisc, iface=iface,
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/supersocket.py", line 254, in __init__
    super(L2bpfListenSocket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/supersocket.py", line 119, in __init__
    attach_filter(self.ins, filter, self.iface)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/core.py", line 155, in attach_filter
    raise Scapy_Exception("Can't attach the BPF filter !")
scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: Can't attach the BPF filter !
/Users/belgra/Development/WiFi Scanner ❯
```

I installed scapy 2.4.5 and am running this code by Python 3.10.1 on M1 Mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share the full output from running the script? Did you run with privileges?

Comment: @pchaigno Thank you for your interest. Yes, I run the script with superuser privileges. But the same result happened. I added the full output and the original script link.

Comment: Could you attach the strace ouput from `strace -f -Z -o strace-output.txt python ...`? That should tell us which syscall is failing.

Comment: Works for me as root on Linux, but I haven't tried on Mac. Are you sure you are running with [sufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63773767/3716552)?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by installing the optional `libpcap` library that Scapy mentions in its installation documentation.

1. Run `brew update` in your terminal
2. Run `brew install libpcap` in your terminal
3. Run Scapy with `scapy` in your terminal
4. Within Scapy run `conf.use_pcap = True`

Here's the [link](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-scapy-v2-x) to the documentation with more info

For reference I am running an M1 MacBook Air (macOS Monterey v12.1) with python 3.8.12.

Comment: libpcap isn't "optional" on macOS - it's a standard part of the OS.  If Scapy can't find the version that ships with the operating system, or can't use it, that's a problem with Scapy.

Comment: Or perhaps if Scapy is installed with Homebrew it doesn't look for the system libpcap, just for a Homebrew installation of libpcap.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error on a M1 MacBook and I solved this by installing and configuring libpcap as @RBPEDIIIAL suggested.